# pjsip call :hangup videocall will block thread when network disconnected

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, pjsip

I have a chat application developed by oc.I'm currently using [pjsip](https://github.com/pjsip/pjproject) library to register to a SIP server using PJSIP.I use `pjsua_call_make_call` to make videoCall,and use `pjsua_call_hangup` to hangup call.when network is reachable,everything is ok .This is a problem when network disconnected. Below are steps to reproduce(audiocall is ok and i have search similar problems but no results) :

1. make videoCall to other,other answer the call to change videoCall state to confirmed
2. i disconnected network
3. i hangup videocall

then issue appear:**thread will be blocked,hangup failure**

*below are log:*

```
14:21:35.527         tsx0x1042f82a8  ....Failed to send Request msg BYE/cseq=2 (tdta0x1042c2ea8)! err=120051 (Network is unreachable)

14:21:35.527         tsx0x1042f82a8  ....State changed from Null to Terminated, event=TRANSPORT_ERROR

14:21:35.527         dlg0x10411a6a8  .....Transaction tsx0x1042f82a8 state changed to Terminated

14:21:35.527           Pjsua_call.c  .......im pjsua_call_get_info get Date Wed, 09 Aug 2017 06:21:06 GMT

14:21:35.527           Pjsua_call.c  .......im pjsua_call_get_info get call_info 1

14:21:35.537        strm0x1042c7a28 !Starting silence

14:21:35.569          pjsua_media.c !.......Call 0: deinitializing media..

14:21:35.569        strm0x1042c7a28  .........JB summary:size=0/eff=0 prefetch=0 level=10 delay (min/max/avg/dev)=360/500/425/45 ms burst (min/max/avg/dev)=1/11/2/2 frames lost=25 discard=29 empty=218

14:21:35.569          pjsua_media.c  .........Media stream call00:0 is destroyed

14:21:35.569            pjsua_vid.c  .........Stopping video stream..

14:21:35.609           darwin_dev.m  ..........Stopping Darwin video stream

14:21:35.663            pjsua_vid.c  ..........Window 1: destroying..

14:21:35.663             vid_port.c  ...........Closing Front Camera..
```

Comment: You have to keep reference of your current call to start with. One thing you may do is to listen for the network connectivity and hang up the call when internet is not available.

Comment: thanks,but the problem is: when internet is not available,i hung up call will block thread

Comment: and now i found the same problem :when IP Address change,i use 'pjsua_call_reinvite()'  ,refer to [link](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/IPAddressChange),also cause same problem and sanme log

Comment: Are you able to solve this issue?

Comment: Any success ? @wuweili

Comment: when i make call use UDP,problem still exist whenever i use my project or pjsip offical  ipjsua.xcodeproj ;but when i use TCP to make call (add ";transport=tcp" parameter to making calls outgoing URIs ) , pjsip offical  ipjsua.xcodeproj work OK. So i think use TCP to make call maybe Optional method.

Comment: i'm sorry ,currently i cannot solve this issue . i will try tcp .@Himanshu